# Using Moles framework to mock static dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moles

I am learning the Moles framework for unit testing. I have a template ASP MVC project with AccountController and the method I want to test is Register()

```cs
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            MembershipCreateStatus createStatus;
            Membership.CreateUser(model.UserName, model.Password, model.Email, null, null, false, null, out createStatus);
            if (createStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
            {
                string confirmationGuid = Membership.GetUser(model.UserName).ProviderUserKey.ToString();
                string confirmUrl = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) +
                    "/account/confirm?id=" + confirmationGuid;
                var message = new MailService.MessageModel
                                  {
                                      UserName = model.UserName,
                                      MessageSubject = "Registration confirmation",
                                      MessageBody = "Please follow the link below in order to activate your account:\n" + confirmUrl
                                  };
                MailService.SendConfrimationEmail(message);
                return RedirectToAction("Confirmation", "Account");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(createStatus));
            }
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

It depends on a static method `Membership.CreateUser`. The test method looks like this:

```
    [TestMethod()]
    [HostType("Moles")]
    public void RegisterTest()
    {
        using (MolesContext.Create())
        {                
            var target = new AccountController();
            var model = new RegisterModel
            {
                UserName = "TestUser1",
                Password = "12345678",
                ConfirmPassword = "12345678",
                Email = "mail@mail.com"
            };
            target.Register(model);
            var exists = Membership.GetUser("TestUser1") != null;
            Assert.IsTrue(exists);
        }
    }
```

I expect the Moles framework to mock the static method inside the `Register` method but while debugging I found that `createStatus` always has `InvalidAnswer` value hence the test fails. 
How can I accomplish this by using Moles framework without creating any interfaces or delegates manually?

Comment: What are the parameters of CreateUser?

Comment: according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152012.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally found a way to mock `Membership.CreateUser` method, although the implementation is a bit long.

```cs
MMembership.CreateUserStringStringStringStringStringBooleanObjectMembershipCreateStatusOut = 
   (string userName, string password, string email, string passwordQuestion, 
    string passwordAnswer, bool isApproved, object providerUserKey,
    out MembershipCreateStatus @createStatus) =>
{
    @createStatus = MembershipCreateStatus.Success;
    return null;
};
```